# ReactJS - Missing Key Despite Key on Element

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing the common `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop` error with my prop component and despite setting a key with the unqiueID of my array for the returned div element I'm seeing this warning. Am I setting it on the wrong element? Could it have something to do with the nested `map`?

**JSON Example:**

```
{
annotationId: 117,
title: "Test",
discovery: "Test 123",
annotation_comments: [{
annotationCommentId: 12,
comment: "Lorem Ipsum"
}]
}
```

**Detailed Error:**

```
in AnnotationCard (created by AnnotationFeed)
    in AnnotationFeed (created by AnnotationFeedContainer)
    in div (created by AnnotationFeedContainer)
    in AnnotationFeedContainer (created by Annotation)
    in div (created by Annotation)
    in Annotation
```

**Components:**

```
//Loop through JSON and component
const AnnotationFeed = props => {
    return (
        <div>
        { 
            props.annotations.map((annotation, index) => {
                return (
                    <AnnotationCard {...annotation}>
                        { annotation.annotation_comments.map((comment, i) => <Comments {...comment} />)}
                    </AnnotationCard>
                );
            })
        }
        </div>
    )
}

const AnnotationCard = props => {
    return (
        <div key={props.annotationIdHash}>
            <h4>{props.title}</h4>
            <p>{props.discovery}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

const Comments = props => {
    return (
        <div key={props.annotationCommentId}>
            <h4>{props.comment}</h4>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You're not setting a key prop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need key here

`<AnnotationCard {...annotation} key={index}>`

and here

`<Comments {...comment} key={i}/>`

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that `AnnotationCard` and `Comments` components need a key property. So you should set a key property for these two components instead of the div tag inside them.